# What is the syntax error in this T-SQL SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this syntax error.

```
SELECT  PROVINCE,
        CASE PROVINCE
            WHEN 'BC'   THEN .12
            WHEN 'AB'   THEN .08
            WHEN 'ON'   THEN .07
            ELSE 0,
        AMOUNT
FROM SALES
```

When I execute the above SQL I get a syntax error:

> Msg 102, Level 15 State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

I'm new to SQL and cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 8):

You're missing "END" at the end of the case statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an 'End' for the case statement that's why you are getting the syntax error.If AMOUNT is a column in Sales table then you should write as:

```
SELECT  PROVINCE,
        CASE PROVINCE
            WHEN 'BC'   THEN .12
            WHEN 'AB'   THEN .08
            WHEN 'ON'   THEN .07
            ELSE 0 
            End as 'NewColumnName',
        AMOUNT
FROM SALES;
```

If you want to have AMOUNT as column name for the case condition then you should write as below:

```
SELECT  PROVINCE,
        CASE PROVINCE
            WHEN 'BC'   THEN .12
            WHEN 'AB'   THEN .08
            WHEN 'ON'   THEN .07
            ELSE 0 end as
        AMOUNT
FROM SALES;
```

Hope this helps!!!